# Excel Conditional Formatting: Highlight cells if not equal

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I ran into a problem, where i want to highlight certain cells based on the input from another cell. Here is my quick example of what I would like to achive:

Highlight `A1:A2` `IF B1` does `NOT` contain the word "`Reactor`"

This is what is used and it did not work:

```
=IF(B1<>(search("Reactor",B1),"",""))
```

Any ideas how to overcome this little problem?Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A1 will be highlighted when:

```
=NOT(IFERROR(SEARCH("reactor",B1)>0,FALSE))
```

[image]

Probably this can be written in more beautiful way... But it works..

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you and have a great weekend!

Answer (score 0):

If you want more than one cell (A1:A2) to be triggered by a single cell (B1) you should anchor B1 (here B$1).

Since if SEARCH fails it will respond with an error, you should be able to apply:

```
=ISERROR(SEARCH("Reactor",B$1))
```

having selected A1:A2 first (or making that your Applies to range).